# Normalize missing value inside an array of objects with nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, normalization

I have this data scenario:

```
var data = [
 {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': null
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': null
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': 'buttons'
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': null
 }, {
  'name': 'icon',
  'group': 'icons'
 }, {
  'name': 'other',
  'group': null
 }, {
  'name': 'icon',
  'group': null
 }
];
```

I would like to normalize this data to this:

```
var data = [
 {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': 'buttons'
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': 'buttons'
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': 'buttons'
 }, {
  'name': 'social-button',
  'group': 'buttons'
 }, {
  'name': 'icon',
  'group': 'icons'
 }, {
  'name': 'other',
  'group': null
 }, {
  'name': 'icon',
  'group': 'icons'
 }
];
```

So basically, I would like to ensure every element which have the same `name` should also have the same `group`, if just one of the same have one.

Does exists some node module could help in this?

Or maybe, does exist some smart way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two loops, one to collect values in a hash table and one to assign.

```js
var data = [{ 'name': 'social-button', 'group': null }, { 'name': 'social-button', 'group': null }, { 'name': 'social-button', 'group': 'buttons' }, {  'name': 'social-button', 'group': null }, { 'name': 'icon', 'group': 'icons' }, { 'name': 'other', 'group': null }, { 'name': 'icon', 'group': null }],
    hash = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.name] = hash[a.name] || a.group;
});

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.group = a.group || hash[a.name];
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You type faster than me :) Though I was going to use `map` to avoid changing the original.

Comment: it looks like a seach for an in-situ solution.

Comment: It worked flawlessly, also didn't changed the order of the items, and finally, it's very easy to read, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could first `sort()` your array so objects with group values come first and then use `map()` to create new array. You can use `Object.assign()` to clone objects so you can don't change your original data.

```js
var data = [{"name":"social-button","group":null},{"name":"social-button","group":null},{"name":"social-button","group":"buttons"},{"name":"social-button","group":null},{"name":"icon","group":"icons"},{"name":"other","group":null},{"name":"icon","group":null}]

var result = data.sort((a, b) => b.group != null).map(function(o) {
  if (!this[o.name]) {
    this[o.name] = o.group
    return o
  } else {
    var obj = Object.assign({}, o);
    obj.group = this[o.name];
    return obj
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in *one pass* by using [*`Array.prototype.reduce`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a `hash table` - see demo below:

```js
var data=[{'name':'social-button','group':null},{'name':'social-button','group':null},{'name':'social-button','group':'buttons'},{'name':'social-button','group':null},{'name':'icon','group':'icons'},{'name':'other','group':null},{'name':'icon','group':null}];

var result = data.reduce((function(hash){
  return function(p,c) {
    hash[c.name] = hash[c.name] || c;
    if(c.group)
      hash[c.name].group = c.group;
    p.push(hash[c.name]);
    return p;
  };
})(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```